# javascript function in variable

Tags: javascript

Im Preety new in Javascript, I have the following function in variable:

```
 var PushToken = {
             getToken: function(types, success, fail) {
                 return Cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushToken", "getToken", types);
             }
         };
```

Now, I'm trying to get the return value from this variable (PushToken) and I can't understand how can I access this variable.

Here is what they suggested in the post I took it from:

```
 PushToken.getToken(     
                     ["getToken"] ,           
                     function(token) {
                              global.token = token; 
                     },
                     function(error) {
                              console.log("Error : \r\n"+error);      
                     }
          );
```

But it still doesn't help me since I don't know how to use it as a variable. How would I do this?

Comment: is this node? have you checked `global.token`?

Comment: Unable to understand what is asked here...

Comment: Sorry i tried to describe it better now.. Thanks!

Comment: add `console.log(token)` inside the success callback... see if that or the `Error..` gets logged.

Comment: what do you mean by "I don't know how to use it as a variable" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the return value from PushToken because it's not a function.
It's an object.
This object has a field getToken which is a function.
By the look of it, it doesn't return value immediately but does it asynchronously using callback function you give it.

Try this code. It should log the result or the error if something goes wrong.

```
var PushToken = {
         getToken: function(types, success, fail) {
             return Cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushToken", "getToken", types);
         }
     };
PushToken.getToken(     
                 ["getToken"] ,           
                 function(token) {
                          //put the code which uses the return value here
                          //this value is inside token variable
                          //for example this should log the value
                          console.log("Token : \r\n"+token);   
                 },
                 function(error) {
                          console.log("Error : \r\n"+error);      
                 }
      );
```

Comment: Sorry for the Delay, Thank you Very much For this! Its work Ok Now!!